# Putting configuration files on a PVC on Openshift

Tags: openshift

I would like to place wildfly's Openshift configuration on a persistent volume so that if the pod crashes I will be able to restore changes in configuration. So I have added a Persistent Volume claim to my WildFly pod mounted on **"/wildfly/standalone/configuration"** however, the Pod fails to start as it cannot find the logging.properties file at boot.
Therefore my question is: can you put configuration folders into a PVC? I assume Openshift won't copy the original configuration XML files into the PVC, isn't it?
Thanks

Comment: You may be better looking at using a config map and mounting that into the container. The config map isn't stored in the persistent volume, but the configuration OpenShift injects into the container.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to add configuration into your application, think config maps. These resources are pieces of configuration used by your application and injected into your application context(as xml/json/ini config files, environment variables etc.) by OpenShift. You can check an example of it [here](https://blog.openshift.com/configuring-your-application-part-1/).